# Compare and Match two values in two databases

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find (or compare) a combination of two values (student id and course number) in columns A and B on Sheet 1 with similar data set on Sheet 2.  In other words, if the combination of student id and course # exists in both Sheet 1 and Sheet 2, return True in Column C.  If not, return a value of False in Column C.  For example,

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

The student IDs can repeat themselves as many as 15 each on both datasets.  Thus, I am looking for when the exact match of ID and Course Number happens.  That's when I need to know whether it's true or false.  My dataset has 4,000+ records in Sheet 1 and about 2400 in Sheet 2.  Thank you.

Comment: Try this one `=IF(AND(A2=Sheet2!A2,B2=Sheet2!B2),"Match","No Match")` in cell C2 of Sheet1 .

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add auxiliary column for example:
[image]

Then enter this formula:

> =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$14,Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B2)>0,"True","False")

[image]

Comment: Omg...yes! It worked perfectly!  Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array Formula with & Operator on the two columns to combine the same and run MATCH function on that Array.

In below screenshots. In Sheet 1 Formula in D3 is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3&C3,Sheet2!$F$3:$F$13&Sheet2!$G$3:$G$13,0)),"True","False")
```

Create an Array Formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar. The formula shall now be automatically enclosed in curly braces. This step is important. If you do not create an Array Formula it may not work correctly.

Drag down the formula up to the intended rows in Sheet1 Table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is perfect!

Comment: This works also!  Thank you soooo much!  So incredibly helpful as I have to use this function constantly!